# Controlling pop-up (dropdown) menu size of a AutoFilterTableHeader for a jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtableheader, jide

How do I control the size of the auto filter pop-up menu for a jtable header. I have some long text as the cell input and the pop-up menu spans across monitors?

[image]

```
columnName =[{'Date'},{'RSS'},{'Title'},{'Description'}];
    DTM = javaObjectEDT(com.jidesoft.grid.DefaultTableModel(data,columnName));
    jtable = javaObjectEDT(com.jidesoft.grid.SortableTable(DTM));
    theader = javaObjectEDT(com.jidesoft.grid.AutoFilterTableHeader(jtable));
    theader.setAutoFilterEnabled(true)
    % theader.setShowFilterName(true)
    theader.setShowFilterIcon(true)
    theader.setAllowMultipleValues(true)
    jtable.setTableHeader(theader)
```

Comment: `auto filter pop-up menu for a jtable header` - that is not a standard Swing component so we don't know how you have implemented that functionality. If you are using a JPopupMenu for the popup then maybe you can use the concept presented in [Combo Box Popup](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/11/28/combo-box-popup/) to control the width. Another option might be to use shorter text but then set a "tooltip" on each item for the longer description.

Comment: I am using com.jidesoft.grid.AutoFilterTableHeader and setting it as table header to com.jidesoft.grid.SortableTable(DTM) (jtable). Where DTM is DefaultTableModel. I use java components and classes through matlab interface so not sure how much sowing you the code will help but have updated the question above.

Comment: If I know the java method to edit it then I can extend AutoFilterTableHeader to take care of the issue. But do not understand the issue completely at this state. I know this is a jide swing class component..for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JIDE grid developers guide doesn't really touch this issue but it is clear that one can extend AutoFilterTableHeader to control the width of the pop-up panel which indeed is a jpanel. Instead of attaching listener to the popup and then changing the width of the panel; I override PopupPanel (including its super classes) and set width equal to width of the current column and it works well.

```
import com.jidesoft.combobox.PopupPanel;
import com.jidesoft.grid.AutoFilterBox;
import com.jidesoft.grid.AutoFilterTableHeader;
import com.jidesoft.grid.AutoFilterTableHeaderEditor;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import java.awt.*;

public class AutoFilterPopSize extends AutoFilterTableHeader
{
    public AutoFilterPopSize(JTable table)
    {
        super(table);
    }

    @Override
    protected TableCellEditor createDefaultEditor()
    {
        if (isAutoFilterEnabled())
        {
            return new AutoFilterTableHeaderEditor()
            {
                @Override
                protected AutoFilterBox createAutoFilterBox()
                {
                    return new AutoFilterBox()
                    {
                        @Override
                        protected PopupPanel createPopupPanel(TableModel tableModel, int columnIndex, Object[] possibleValues)
                        {
                            PopupPanel panel = super.createPopupPanel(tableModel, columnIndex, possibleValues);
                            panel.setStretchToFit(false);
                            int wdth = columnModel.getColumn(columnIndex).getWidth();
                            panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(wdth, 400));
                            return panel;
                        }
                    };
                }
            };
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

But still remains one unresolved issue; when jide's custom filter is selected and a condition is set, the dialog box size is still spanning across the monitors. Any ideas on how to fix that now? Any direction you give would be helpful to a non programmer like me. Thank you.

Popup Width set properly
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIMIT.png]

Custom Filter Dialog size still messed up
[image]